# PHP - How to Backup and Move Wordpress Blog Website to different directory on the same host

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql, phpmyadmin

I setup a blog for development purposes on the ***.com/a/ directory and now want to move it to the root directory ***.com on the same host.

How do I Backup and Move the Wordpress Blog Website to the Root Directory on the SAME host?

I'm looking at a tutorial on [WordpressSites.net](http://wordpresssites.net/site-move/backup-site-move-wordpress-host-wordpress-plugin/) & [howtospoter.com](http://www.howtospoter.com/web-20/wordpress/howto-move-wordpress-to-new-host/comment-page-2#comment-30294) but am pretty sure I can skip some of these steps because I am using the same hosting service and just need to change a couple settings right?

Here are the steps require to completely change hosting companies:

- Complete Full Backup of Your WordPress Site
- Setup Your New Database at Your New Host
- Change Your Existing DNS Domain Name Servers To Point To Your New Host
- Upload and Import Your WordPress Backup To Your New Hosts Database
- Configure Your Import Settings For Restoration and Completion To Your New Host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress codex has step-by-step instructions for [Moving WordPress Within Your Site:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

> 1. Create the new location using one of these two options: If you will be
>      moving your WordPress core files to a
>      new directory, create the new
>      directory. If you want to move
>      WordPress to your root directory, make
>      sure all index.php, .htaccess, and
>      other files that might be copied over
>      are backed up and/or moved, and that
>      the root directory is ready for the
>      new WordPress files.
> 2. Login to your blog. Go to the Administration > Settings > General
>      panel.
> 3. In the box for WordPress address (URI): change the address to the new
>      location of your main WordPress core
>      files.
> 4. In the box for Blog address (URI): change the address to the new
>      location, which should match the
>      WordPress address (URI).
> 5. Click Save Settings.
> 6. (Do not try to open/view your blog now!)
> 7. WordPress 2.0 only: Delete the folder wp-content/cache.
> 8. Move your WordPress core files to the new location. This includes the
>      files found within the original
>      directory, such as
>      `http://example.com/wordpress`, and all
>      the sub-directories, to the new
>      location.
> 9. If you are using Permalinks, go to the Administration > Settings >
>      Permalinks panel and update your
>      Permalink structure to your .htaccess
>      file, which should be in the same
>      directory as the main index.php file.
> 10. If you have problems with missing images that you've uploaded, you need
>       to change the path to the images on
>       every post directly on your SQL
>       database. For this, follow the
>       instructions on Tamba2's Tutorial
>       "Moving your weblog inside your PC".
> 11. You must also check and edit 'store uploads folder' under Settings >
>       Media or all your new uploads will continue to go into the old folder.
> 12. Existing image/media links uploaded media will refer to the old
>       folder and must be updated with the
>       new location.
> 13. In some cases your permissions may have changed, depending on your ISP.
>       Watch for any files with "0000"
>       permissions and change them back to
>       "0644".
> 14. If your theme supports menus, links to your home page may still have
>       the old subdirectory embedded in them.
>       Go to Appearance::Menus and update
>       them.
>
> It is important that you set the URI
>   locations BEFORE you move the files.

Comment: thanks for your response! I added the step-by-step instructions onto the answer. Hopefully it gets approved. :)